# How to give someone a timeout in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I would like to know how to give someone a timeout (Discord's own system, not the role cycle method) in discord.py.
And I would like to give a timeout by entering the time unit (ex. 1m, 2h, 3d).
I store two discord usernames and discord ids in the database, so it's okay to use target_username as the discord username.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands, Interaction, ui, Member, User, utils
from discord.ui import Button, View
import sqlite3
import datetime
from humanfriendly import parse_timespan

class warn(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot

    class warn_modal(discord.ui.Modal, title='경고 지급하기'):
        def __init__(self, bot):
            super().__init__()
            self.bot = bot
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
            self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

        target_username = ui.TextInput(label='대상(target)', placeholder='Please enter the target Discord username.', required=True)
        warn_amount = ui.TextInput(label='경고(warn)', placeholder='지급할 경고의 수를 입력해주세요.(
Please enter the number of warnings to be paid.)', required=False)
        timeout_duration = ui.TextInput(label='타임아웃(timeout)', placeholder='지급할 타임아웃의 지속시간을 입력해주세요.(Please enter the duration of timeout to be paid.)', required=False)
        reason = ui.TextInput(label='사유(reason)', placeholder='처벌 사유를 입력합니다.(
Enter the reason for punishment.)', required=True)

        async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
            server_id = interaction.guild.id

            warn_amount = self.warn_amount.value
            if warn_amount:
                warn_amount = int(warn_amount)
                if warn_amount <= 0:
                    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), title='오류(error)', description='
The number of warnings must be a natural number.'))
                    return
            else:
                warn_amount = 0

            timeout_duration = self.timeout_duration.value
            if timeout_duration:
                timeout_duration = int(timeout_duration)
            else:
                timeout_duration = 0

            giver_username = str(interaction.user)
            giver_userid = interaction.user.id

            target_usrename = self.target_username.value
            self.cur.execute("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username=?", (target_usrename,))
            target_userid = self.cur.fetchone()[0]

            self.cur.execute("SELECT warn FROM users WHERE username=? AND server=?", (target_usrename, server_id))
            current_warn = self.cur.fetchone()[0]

            new_warn = current_warn + warn_amount
            reason = self.reason.value

            async def button1_callback(interaction):
                self.cur.execute('''
                    UPDATE users
                    SET warn=?
                    WHERE username=? AND server=?
                ''', (new_warn, target_usrename, server_id))
                now = datetime.datetime.now()

                

                embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title='처벌 완료', description=f"{target_usrename}({target_userid})님에게 경고 {warn_amount}회와 {timeout_duration}시간 타임아웃을 지급했습니다. 사유: {reason}")

                embed.set_footer(text = str(now.year)+'년 '+str(now.month)+'월 '+str(now.hour)+'시 '+str(now.minute)+'분 '+str(now.second)+'초 '+ str(giver_username)+'('+str(giver_userid)+')')

                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed, view=None)

                self.conn.commit()
                self.conn.close()

            async def button2_callback(interaction):
                embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title='처벌 취소', description=f"처벌을 취소했습니다.")
                await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed, view=None)

            accept = Button(label="확인", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
            deny = Button(label="취소", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)

            accept.callback = button1_callback
            deny.callback = button2_callback

            view = View()
            view.add_item(accept)
            view.add_item(deny)

            embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.blue(), title='경고 지급 확인', description=f'{target_usrename}님에게 경고 {warn_amount}회와 {timeout_duration}시간 타임아웃을 지급하시겠습니까?')
            msg = await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=view)

    @app_commands.command(name='처벌', description='유저에게 경고 및 타임아웃을 지급합니다.')
    async def warn(self, interaction: Interaction) -> None:
        await interaction.response.send_modal(warn.warn_modal(self.bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

With command:

```
from datetime import timedelta

@bot.command()
async def timeout(ctx:commands.Context):
    duration = timedelta(seconds=60)
    await ctx.author.timeout(duration)
```

With slash commands:

```
from datetime import timedelta

@bot.tree.command(name="timeout2")
async def timeout2(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    duration = timedelta(seconds=60)
    await interaction.user.timeout(duration)
    await interaction.response.send_message("Timed out")
```

These will try to time out whoever executes them, it will raise an error of Missing Permissions this is because you are superior to the bot (It can't time you out), but if you change it and time out someone else it will work.